# C file transfer socket

Tags: c, sockets, file-transfer

```
void RecvFile() 
{ 
int rval; 
char buf[0x1000]; 
FILE *file = fopen("C:\\pic.bmp", "wb"); 
if (!file)
{
    printf("Can't open file for writing");
    return;
}

do
{
    rval = recv(winsock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if (rval < 0)
    {
        // if the socket is non-blocking, then check
        // the socket error for WSAEWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN
        // (depending on platform) and if true then
        // use select() to wait for a small period of
        // time to see if the socket becomes readable
        // again before failing the transfer...

        printf("Can't read from socket");
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }

    if (rval == 0)                 
        break; //line 159

    int off = 0;
    do
    {
        int written = fwrite(&buf[off], 1, rval - off, file);
        if (written < 1)
        {
            printf("Can't write to file");
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }

        off += written;
    }
    while (off < rval)
} //line 175

fclose(file); 
}
```

> 175 syntax error before '}' token  
>   159 confused by earlier errors, bailing out

I dont know what to do... can you help me?
I'm still kinda new in c programming.
I have inserted error lines in the code.
what i can't understand is why is this error ocurring... Can you guys explain me why?

Comment: yeah how can I fix it? I can't just delete it can I? I think it is an error check...

Comment: That is rather horrible way to indent do-while loop... Try having `do {` or at least `} while(...);` as one line, do not split them. You probably would have spotted the error yourself with different indentation...

Comment: OT: The preferred type to store result from `read()`/`recv()`and `write()`/`send()` are `ssize_t`. For `fread()` and `fwrite()` it's `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are missing `;` at while loop

```
while (off < rval);   // 174 line
                  ^
```

second outer loop there is no while

```
do{

}// 175 line
while()  // this is missing ???
```

I am not 100% sure But I think you need infinite loop at outer like (a rough code below)
Read comments:

```
do{

   // rev = recv(....
   if(rev <){
    // you return from here that is reason i believe you need infinite loop 
    // code
   }
   //code
   do{
       // your code
   }while (off < rval); // at like 174
}while(1); // line 175
```

Answer (score 0):

At line 175, you are supposed to have a `while` statement as you have a corresponding do statement in the beginning. A semicolon is also missing for another do-while statement in your code.

```
void RecvFile() 
{ 
int rval; 
char buf[0x1000]; 
FILE *file = fopen("C:\\pic.bmp", "wb"); 
if (!file)
{
    printf("Can't open file for writing");
    return;
}

do //******Where is the while for this do statement?*****
{
    rval = recv(winsock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if (rval < 0)
    {
        // if the socket is non-blocking, then check
        // the socket error for WSAEWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN
        // (depending on platform) and if true then
        // use select() to wait for a small period of
        // time to see if the socket becomes readable
        // again before failing the transfer...

        printf("Can't read from socket");
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }

    if (rval == 0)                 
        break; //line 159

    int off = 0;
    do
    {
        int written = fwrite(&buf[off], 1, rval - off, file);
        if (written < 1)
        {
            printf("Can't write to file");
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }

        off += written;
    }
    while (off < rval) // *** A semicolon is needed here ***
} //line 175

fclose(file); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget a semicolon after the `do...while` block

change

`while (off < rval)` to `while (off < rval);`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes.

1. `while (off < rval)` should be replaced with `while (off < rval);`
2. You are missing a `while` statement for the first `do`